# How to uniquely identify a network?

Tags: security, networking, network-programming, identity

Let's say I want to make an application where stored data is encrypted so only my application is able to read it.

But I want the application to be accessed only if the user is on a particular network.
For instance the application is an Android app that deals with medical records in a hospital.
How to be sure that the device is connected to the network of the hospital ? The idea is that outside this network, the app won't work.

The question is not particularly related to wireless networks, wireless devices or Android, this is general to programming and network identification.

Could a certificate do that ? I'm new to this.
Does a network "identifier" could be faked ? For instance I'm pretty sure that a WiFi SSID is easy to fake.

Cheers.

More details:
Let's assume that the point of the local data is not for an "offline mode", but to avoid network latency. In that case, the data needs to remain accessible only if connected to a particular network, in case the device is stolen.

But if there is no way to be sure of the network's identity... What about a server that would answer to the question "Heya am I on the right network ?" and if no response comes out I know that I'm not on the right one ? (Or that the server just does not respond...) But, again, if the app is hacked, that can be faked too.

Comment: Yeah thanks @blowdart, and sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem.

Generally speaking the purpose of storing data locally is so that it can be accessed while "offline".

However, I think there may be some underlying misconceptions here.  Presumably the only reason you'd want to do this is to try and prevent a stolen device from giving up it's secrets.  Fact of the matter is, you can't.  If the device is no longer under your physical control then it's just a matter of time before it can be hacked.

If we are talking about sensitive data, it shouldn't be stored on the devices.  Instead the device should retrieve the data it needs from your server when it needs it and delete it locally when no longer necessary.

The fact that you want the device to only work when connected to your local network implies that you can accomplish this goal.

As a side note, this is why things such as "remote wipe" exist.  It's also why every time the device connects to your network it needs to test it's authentication and authorization.  Point is if someone reports the device lost or stolen then you need to be able to ban it from your network AND, if the device supports this, remotely disable it.

Bearing in mind that it is entirely possible to pull a device from the network and therefore disable a remote wipe from executing.

---

With that out of the way, there is absolutely no way you can ensure the device is on a given network.  All of that can be faked.  It's kind of trivial to setup a router of a given name and change it's MAC to masquerade as whatever, and assign it certain IP addresses.  For all intents and purposes it could be made to look exactly like an access point you have... And that's just with normal run of the mill wireless routers you can buy at your local computer store.

Comment: Agree with the misconception fact. If the point of the local data is that it can be accessed while offline, trying to identify the network is pointless...

Comment: Thanks for the "remote wipe", I will take a look at that too.

Answer (score 3):

You could write your program so that the key to decrypt the data is stored on a server on the hospital network. If your program never stores the key, it makes it harder (although not impossible) for someone to access the device's data outside of the network.

As Chris pointed out a remote wipe would definitely be desirable. You could put in logic so that if the device ever attempts to read the data while not connected to the network, it wipes the data (this might lead to unintended wipes). Blacklisting is good too, so that if the device tries to reconnect to the network, you can essentially brick it. One thing that would be really bad is if you have a network outage, and all your devices accidentally get wiped.

Comment: The first paragraph has the right idea - the only way to do this securely is to ensure that something that is technically required to read the data is only available on the right network.  You should though use many keys - one per record, say - and have the application forget the key immediately after using it.

Comment: +1. With the idea of erring on the side of caution I for one would like to have the devices accidentally wiped in the event of a network outage.

Comment: But when the key is retrieved from the server I'm subject to a Man-in-the-middle attack. Right ?

Comment: I'm definitely not a security expert, but you could use a secure method of transferring the key (SSL). Even if someone can sniff the key, they would need to also access the device and your decryption methods program to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Any network can duplicate another's SSID, so that's not reliable. You could start using a combination of SSID and a MAC address of a known router, but MAC addresses can be duplicated (although not on the same network) so that doesn't work either.

Frankly, unless the wireless network in question is using certificates to identify devices you're going to have no reliable way do it it, and even then this supposes you have a way in your application to get the certificate used the wifi network returns during network authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use IPSec tunnels. Many routers and firewalls support IPSec. What I'm thinking is something like this:

```
                             ----------------------------------- 
                            /            IPSec tunnel           \
                       +---------+                               \
                     A |  IPSec  | B      Untrusted               \
trusted network -------| capable |-------  Networks  ----------- Your application
                       | router  |      Internet, etc.
                       +---------+
```

The gateway router/firewall that provides access for the trusted network has an IPSec tunnel configured between itself and your application. On both the router and your application server, the tunnel looks like another network interface. A route on the router directs traffic for your application to the tunnel interface. A filter can be used on the router to ensure traffic is forwarded to the tunnel *only if* it arrives on interface `A` (i.e. the trusted network). Traffic arriving on interface `B` destined to your application can just be dropped by a filter on the router since it's obviously going the wrong way.

If your application binds its listening socket to just the tunnel interface, you'll know you're only accepting connections received over the tunnel.

You can use whatever combination of encryption and authentication mechanisms you want to to ensure the traffic is secure. Most IPSec implementations support just about anything you could want.